# Why network hashrate fall when price go up?

Tags: hashrate, price

Its really strange for me, price for week is bull as hell and in this same time hashrate ethereum is decreasing, can anyone tell my why?

Comment: Where are you seeing the hash rate decrease? From the charts, it has been increasing all week, with a slight dip in the past 24 hours. (I think the dip on the 4th was probably some sort of artefact.) (https://www.coinwarz.com/network-hashrate-charts/ethereum-network-hashrate-chart, https://etherscan.io/chart/hashrate)

Comment: I am using whattomine.com and there is still decreasing, week ago there was something like 128Th/s now there is 119Th/s, but my bad I do not look on other resources